# Показ пароля в форме регистрации

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, дорогие друзья! Как выполнить форму регистрации как у Яндекса https://passport.yandex.ru/registration?mode=register.? Очень интересует часть c показом пароля.

Answer (score 1):

html тег `<input>` имеет атрибут `type`, который определяет как будет отображаться само поле ввода и его содержимое (может меняться при помощи css). Подробнее о возможных типах здесь http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type. При `type="text"` содержимое поля отображается нормально, а при `type="password"` оно заменяется звездочками/точками. Так вот яндекс меняет тип поля с `text` на `password` и наоборот (убедиться в этом можно, ткнув ПКМ -> исследовать элемент на поле ввода пароля).
С использованием jquery это можно реализовать так:

```
('.show-icon').click(function() {
    if ($('#password').prop('type') == 'text') {
        $('#password').prop('type', 'password')
    } else {
        $('#password').prop('type', 'text')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> Очень интересует часть c показом пароля.

Меняется тип `input`а с `password` на `text`. Современные браузеры без проблем умеют так делать. В старых браузерах подобное изменение могло кончаться исключением, поэтому такой код следует оборачивать в try-catch. Вообще, где-то видел, что элемент пытались сначала убирать из DOM'а, потом менять ему тип, после чего возвращать обратно. Но не думаю, что следует заморачиваться на эту тему.

Другой вариант, сделать label с pointer-events:none и положить его вместе с input'ом в контейнер, который будет подстраиваться под input. А label растянуть абсолютным позиционированием и поместить наверх. Не забыть обработку ввода.

Кстати, IE11 умеет показывать пароль при удерживании кнопки. Ту кнопку можно стилизовать.

Answer (score 0):

Часть с показом пароля - https://github.com/cloudfour/hideShowPassword

Проверка на сложность пароля - http://git.aaronlumsden.com/strength.js/

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).